# Color coding top-bar menu tabs Zurb Foundation

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, sass, zurb-foundation

I'm kind of new to this so hopefully this will be helpful to more people than myself.

I'm using Zurb's Foundation and need to color code each tab in the top-bar menu kind of like [USA Today](http://www.usatoday.com/)'s menu (but with dropdowns). From the setting.scss file there are options for topBar properties (height, colors etc.) and this affect all tabs of the dropdown.

How would you go about creating subsections for the topBar menu, each with its own colors?

Answer (score 0):

You could add classes to all the menu items, or use the [`:nth-child` pseudoclass](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3anth-child) to assign a different border color to each menu item.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, seems like I have loads to learn still :) The nth-child pseudoclass is very interesting but I'm not sure it's what I need at this point. Is there a way to target specific menu items based on words they contain (e.g. if menu elements contains word "Contact" then it should have a pink background)